# Why "new Date()" returns time on different format, depending which Node server I run it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I run new Date() on my local node I get it in UTC format:

```
2017-08-16T10:04:45.809Z
```

If I run it on my test server, I get

```
Wed Aug 16 2017 12:04:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Both times are correct. In neither cases the result is string, as far as I know. Why am I getting different format for the date, depending where I run the function? What can affect the output of new Date()?

Comment: Different locale settings ...

Comment: time zone differs for two different systems. Your output is correct but you are getting this difference because of time zone difference.

Comment: Well, the both machines are actually running on same timezone, but apparently, I assume, I have not set timezone to my local Node...

Answer (score 2):

new Date() returns a date object. What you see is the date object converted to string (to print it out) applying the locale that can be different on two machines. Please, also note that new Date() returns the date and time including time zone set on the machine where the command is executed